# E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I know that there are already several questions similar to this, but none of its solutions worked for me. Hence, after a lot of web searching and trying out different stuff, I simply decided to open a Stack Overflow question myself.

Basically, I had ROS Kinetic working on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and it suddenly started giving me several errors when I tried to build my catkin workspace. After trying several stuff, I decided to uninstall ROS with `sudo apt-get remove ros-*` and install it again, according to the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu.

I leave below the full execution of the installation commands:

```
tomas@tomas-TOSHIBA:~ $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
tomas@tomas-TOSHIBA:~ $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
Executing: /tmp/tmp.plh6QKA5mU/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv-key
C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
gpg: requesting key AB17C654 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key AB17C654: "Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
tomas@tomas-TOSHIBA:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease  
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Fetched 325 kB in 6s (50.3 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
tomas@tomas-TOSHIBA:~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I already tried using curl and the different links they suggest on the tutorial to setup my keys, but the end result was the same. If I try `sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full`, I get:

```
tomas@tomas-TOSHIBA:~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ros-desktop-full : Depends: ros-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-perception but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Running `sudo aptitude install ros-desktop-full` also did not work. If I execute `sudo apt-get install ros-desktop`, it says that `ros-desktop` has unmet dependencies. If I try to install those dependencies, they also have unmet dependencies.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those suffering from the same problem, I was not able to solve it and ended up reinstalling Ubuntu on my computer. After this, everything worked correctly.

My advice would be to just reinstall Ubuntu right away, I would have lost less time if I had done it immediately.